# move to next row repeat process vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with column A listing a series of risks.

Column F lists items that can mitigate these risks.
I want to write a script to identify if the risks in a have a control or do not have a control
for example

```
A                  F
Risk7              control
                   monitor
                   test
Risk8              (blank)
```

so output would be 1 risk with a control and one risk without

my script so far is

```
Sub CountWithWithoutControls()

' counts number of risks with controls and without controls, 
' currently running through each cell and comparing back to original control, 
' need to write to get it to walk down the series

 Dim cell As Range
 Dim myrange As Range
 Dim control As Long
 Dim WoControl As Long

 Set myrange = Range("a7:f27")

 For Each cell In myrange     
     If Range("c7") <> "" And Range("f7") = "Control" Then control = control + 1
     If Range("c7") <> "" And Range("f7") <> "Control" Then WoControl = WoControl + 1     
 Next cell

 MsgBox control & "  = number of risks with controls" & WoControl & ("  = number of risks without controls")

 End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA and while I don't think this should be that hard I'm not making any progress.  any hints in the right direction would be most appreciated!
thank you all
Paul

Comment: Is your range dynamic or static?

Comment: try `For Each row In myrange.Rows`. Then you would need to modify your logic within your loop to only check that row's info rather than using absolute references

Comment: Also, your `If` statements in your `for each` loop don't actually change when the loop changes. I *think* you want to do `If Cells(row,3).Value <> "" and Cells(row,6).Value = "Control"...`, following @Taelsin's suggestion.

Comment: thank you for your help that makes sense...I get a type mismatch error though  If Cells(lRow, "A") <> "" And Cells(lRow, "F") = "Control" Then  can you point me in the right area to fix it?  thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should check each "block" of risks to see whether "Control" (case-insensitive) appears within the block.

I wasn't sure whether the Risks were in column A or column C (both seem to get mentioned in the question and other answers) so I have used constants to define the columns and start row - change them as appropriate.

(Updated to allow for blank rows within data)

```
Sub CountWithWithoutControls()
    Const RiskColumn As String = "C"
    Const ControlColumn As String = "F"
    Const StartAtRow As Long = 7

    Dim r As Long
    Dim ControlFound As Boolean
    Dim control As Long
    Dim WoControl As Long

    Dim lastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Range(RiskColumn & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        r = .Range(ControlColumn & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow < r Then
            lastRow = r
        End If

        ControlFound = False
        For r = StartAtRow To lastRow
            If UCase(Trim(CStr(.Cells(r, ControlColumn).Value))) = "CONTROL" Then
                ControlFound = True
            End If
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(r + 1, RiskColumn)) Then
                'Store info for previous block each time we encounter a new "risk"
                If ControlFound Then
                    control = control + 1
                Else
                    WoControl = WoControl + 1
                End If
                ControlFound = False
            End If
        Next
        'Store info for final "block"
        If ControlFound Then
            control = control + 1
        Else
            WoControl = WoControl + 1
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox control & "  = number of risks with controls, " & WoControl & "  = number of risks without controls"
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you this helps...the risk column is C sorry for the mistake.  i edited that but the loop appears to end when i have a cell in column c and in column f are blank.  to that point, it called out correctly the risk with and without a control.  can you point me in the right direction to take the loop down the page?  sorry for the dumb question and thank you for your help

Comment: @Pauliec - I have updated the answer to allow for blank rows inside the data.  (Previously it stopped as soon as there were blanks in both the control **and** risk column, now it will go until the last row where either of the columns is non-blank.)

Comment: thank you again.  I get a run time error on this line  If UCase(Trim(.Cells(r, ControlColumn).Value)) = "CONTROL" Then           thoughts on fixing?  I see there was a do and exit do on the first iteration and wondering if it needs inserted again but not sure.  thank you again

Comment: (a) It looks like that line will crash in some cases, e.g. if one of the cells contains a "#DIV/0!".  I've edited the answer to put a `CStr` function in there too - that should fix it.  (b) It doesn't need an `Exit Do` anymore - the original code kept going forever until it found blank cells at which point it did the `Exit Do`, but the edit to handle blank rows within the data changed the code to first work out the specific rows to look at (the `StartAtRow` and `lastRow` variables) and then just loop across those rows.

Comment: That works!!!!  thank you very much for your help.  I was having the hardest time trying to figure out how to get it to roll through the areas specific to that risk.  it's been to date a largely manual process but the rows keep getting longer so this will be a huge help!  thank you again!!

Comment: I'm attempting to build on this...the sheet populates a report for risks-with without controls, then the ones with controls-how many have tests monitors how many do not, etc.   Is it possible to next if then statements inside of a for next loop?  that is, if control and monitor and test, then it's a control with a test and monitor. I put code similar to yours but I'm getting a for next error .  Do you tutor?  Thank you

Comment: @Pauliec - it's better to create a new question, as there won't be enough room in a comment to help you, and editing the answer based on extra requirements posted in comments is usually "frowned on" (with good reason) in SO.  In the new question, post the code that you are now using, and explain what results you are after.  (I **think** you are after:  of the "blocks" that have a control record, how many have a "test" record, how many have a "monitor" record, how many have both.  But you may have other records, and therefore other combinations, so make sure you explain those in the question.)

Comment: great thank you for the etiquette tip.  will do post here shortly.  you're correct, it's a matter of identifying the different combinations.  thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I propose this correction

```
 For Each cell In range("F7:F27")
     if cell.offset(,-3)<>"" then ' check if cell in column C is not empty 
        if cell = "Control" then control=control+1 else WoControl=WoControl+1   
     end if
 Next cell
```

Comment: this works thank you.  quick question, what would be the best way to expand the are to review in column f?  that is, say the risk in c has 4 line items mitigating.  (procedure, monitor, test, control)  as is, it would call it without a control because it's out of order but I'd like to be able to have it scan the fields until the next risk occurs in column c

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, I think in your case it's better to use a `For` loop on rows, scanning the values in **Column A** and **Column F** (instead of the entire range).

```
Sub CountWithWithoutControls()

' counts number of risks with controls and without controls,
' currently running through each cell and comparing back to original control,
' need to write to get it to walk down the series

Dim cell As Range
'Dim myrange As Range
Dim control As Long
Dim WoControl As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

'Set myrange = Range("A7:F27")

' find last row in Column A - risks
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For lRow = 7 To LastRow
    If Cells(lRow, "A") <> "" And Cells(lRow, "F") = "Control" Then control = control + 1
    If Cells(lRow, "A") <> "" And Cells(lRow, "F") <> "Control" Then WoControl = WoControl + 1
Next lRow

MsgBox control & "  = number of risks with controls; " & WoControl & " = number of risks without controls"

End Sub
```